# how can i get the object of a button created with storyboard

Tags: ios, uiview, storyboard

I created a button on a view controller by dragging the icon of button in storyboard. I thought this would generate an object. is there an approach that I can get the id, i.e. the object of that button? Is there a method that we designate a label or identifier for that button and we can refer to it with certain methods?
Thanks in advance for answering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you drag a button from the object library onto your storyboard's scene, when that scene is instantiated at runtime, the object associated for that button will be created. If you want to have a reference to that object so you can interact with it programmatically, you can open the assistant editor:

[image: assistant editor]

You will want to make sure you set the custom class for your view controller and you simplify your life a little if you tell your assistant editor to "automatically" select choose the right associated .h file:

[image: set class and use automatic mode]

You can then <kbd>control</kbd>-drag (or right-click-drag) from the button down to assistant editor window and create either an outlet (an `IBOutlet`) or an action (an `IBAction`):

[image: outlet]

By doing that, you then have a reference to the button object that is created when the scene is instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Assistan Editor (Split View, so that you see Interface Builder on the Left and Your View Controller on the right.)
2. Ctrl-Klick & Drag on the button and drag it to the Controller (you'll see a blue line).
3. An `IBOutlet` will be generated in your ViewController and you can access it.