# Which the method recommended by Apple allow me to connect the outlet in Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iboutlet

What is the technical difference between them and which is the method recommended by Apple?

// 1

```
@interface CocoaQuizViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
}
@end
```

// 2

```
@interface CocoaQuizViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
@end
```

// 3

```
@interface CocoaQuizViewController : UIViewController
{
    UILabel *myLabel;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
@end
```

// 4

```
@interface CocoaQuizViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
@end
```

Comment: Off topic: Use ARC if you can.

Answer (score 3):

The default is (generated automatically if you drag and drop outlet directly from xib to source class):

```
@interface CocoaQuizViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
@end
```

Comment: If you are using ARC, this is the one. If you use retain (above) by implication you are not using ARC and you have to remember to release your interface (bad news).

Answer (score 2):

All are quite OK.

With new LLVM you are supposed to do 4th one.

```
@interface CocoaQuizViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
//even you use strong and weak intead of retain,assign,copy
@end
```

In earlier days, you were doing 1, 2 and 3. Now most of the thing is atomatcally done by the compiler. So your work is now easier than never before.

With New Compiler which comes with XCode4.4 and onwards gives you auto-synthesize for all the properties you declare. ivars also get created prefixed with your property name.

Answer (score 1):

The 4th one, Because Now Apple has recommended all developers to make use of properties.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of thoughts:

1. Your fourth example avoids a whole category of possible bugs that can plague the first three examples, where you can accidentally end up with two ivars (e.g. if you omitted the `@synthesize`, the compiler would generate an ivar called `_myLabel`, your `myLabel` ivar wouldn't be used, and, thus, would end up being redundant and only serve as a possible source of confusion).
2. If you use ARC (which I'd encourage, if you can), then clearly that `retain` reference becomes `weak`.
3. You probably shouldn't be "writing" the `IBOutlet` code yourself anyway. It's just an opportunity to introduce a bug. In IB, click on the "assistant editor" to show your code while working on IB, and then <kbd>control</kbd>-drag (or right-click-drag) from the control to the code, and IB will write your code for you! See https://stackoverflow.com/a/15551101/1271826 for screen snapshots.